# Wiping portable hard drive with DD in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

I’ve got 3 portable hard drives one is 160GB, the other two are 500GB. I want to write zeros to them using Linux and [`dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd). I found this command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=?
```

How for the block size, what is the ideal block size for my 3 portable hard drives? (Note: I placed the `?` at the end of the command.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `bs=` value, I would recommend setting `1024` like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1024
```

But if you are paranoid about data recovery—and want to do something “stronger” than just write zeros—you could use [`/dev/urandom`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom) instead like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda bs=1024
```

#### An alternative way to wipe a drive.

But personally, I don’t like to use `dd` for a task like this. Instead I use a slight variant where I format the drive—and repartitioning if it needs to be repartitioned—and then run the following command. Note that while some might consider this method as supposedly being “inefficient,” you really have to be extremely distrusting of the way partitions and file systems work to believe this method is not a viable alternate method:

```
cat /dev/zero >> /path/to/mounted/drive/junk_file &
```

Or this variant using the `/dev/urandom` device as explained above `dd` example:

```
cat /dev/urandom >> /path/to/mounted/drive/junk_file &
```

Just change `/path/to/mounted/drive/` to the actual path of the mounted drive. What that does is create a file called `junk_file` on the filesystem and do it as a background process with the `&` appended to the end.

The nice thing about an operation like this is you can stop it and resume it later. Meaning it’s just a file filled with zeros or urandom junk. So let’s say you need to shut down the machine or disconnect the drive. Just do that. And then run that same command again and let it continue where it started. This is useful when wiping data from really large drives that might take hours to complete.

For more details on these—and other—secure device/file deletion methods, check out [this page on the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk#shred). The tips are useful for pretty much any Linux/Unix—even Mac OS X—system and not just ArchLinux.

#### Speed of the data wiping operation.

As for speed, the overall speed of this type of operation can be estimated by how long it would take your system to copy a 160GB or 500GB file to that same drive. Since writing a file like this is really the data equivalent of “copying” a file; just in this case a file is being created.

FWIW, `/dev/urandom` will take longer to do it’s thing than `/dev/zero`—because `/dev/urandom` is actually generating randomized data—so keep that in mind if time is a factor.

Comment: How long would this take on my my 160GB drive?

Comment: Asuming you have USB 2.0, then the writing speed will be around 25-30MB/s. This gives you ~100 minutes for the 160GB drive and ~5.5 hours for each of the 500GB disks. Bottom line: USB 2.0 sucks, USB 3.0 rocks.

Comment: @alesc - Thanks my good man. I'm using USB 2.0, but it doesn't bother me how slow it is.

Comment: Or you could use `shred /dev/sda`...

Comment: 512 bytes is extremely wastefully slow. You'll incur huge overhead. Go for at least `bs=1M` or you'll be twiddling your thumbs for ages. As for recommending to source data from `/dev/random`, that is a *terrible* idea; [`/dev/random` is for long-term-use crypto keys and similar, not for bulk data!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random). If you want a lot of strong random data, you need to use `/dev/urandom` instead.

Comment: A **dd** command applied to the whole drive will perform a systematic write to ***every*** sector of the drive.  Your alternative method of re-partitioning and writing to a "junk_file" cannot guarantee that every sector of the drive is re-written.  Therefore your alternative is an inferior method for wiping the drive.

Answer (score 0):

[I wrote this as a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/977219/wiping-portable-hard-drive-with-dd-in-linux#comment1341860_977223), but I’m going to put it as an answer too for visibility.

For the `dd` block size, you want a big enough buffer that the program isn't just constantly issuing system calls for trivial amounts of I/O. Having copied a lot of disks using `dd`, **I recommend at least `bs=1M`, or even something like `16M`**. If your disk size isn't an exact multiple of your block size then you'll leave a tiny bit of un-overwritten data at the end; it's a safe bet there's nothing there at all but if you want to be paranoid you could manually get that last bit.

Using a small block size (with `/dev/zero` or any other source) will slow you down, but that's nothing compared to the slowdown you'd get from using a blocking data source like `/dev/random`, which is what the accepted answer suggests at the time of writing. The purpose of `/dev/random` is to generate *maximum-entropy* data, not to generate *lots* of data. It's not just that it’s slow, but that it draws from an entropy pool of limited size, and the pool doesn't refill very quickly(especially if you aren't doing anything else with the system).

When the pool runs out, reading from `/dev/random` will block, refusing to supply any more data until the pool refills. You use `/dev/random` for things like long-term cryptographic keys, not for bulk data. **Trying to pull half a terabyte from `/dev/random` is an absolutely terrible idea.** If you want a lot of high-entropy data, you need to *use `/dev/urandom` instead*. It uses pseudo-random generators to stretch the entropy pool to an arbitrary size, giving up some entropy in exchange for making sure that a read on it will always succeed in reasonable time.

Comment: (cont'd) The last half is interesting and possibly useful information, but now not in a useful place because nobody will find it except accidentally.  CBHacking, suggestion: post a new question about /dev/random vs. /dev/urandom and self-answer with the relevant portion of this answer (and just delete this answer from here).

Comment: @fixer1234: OK, might do that. Yeah, sorry, I didn't see the updated answer until after I'd posted.